# Fit to scale in webview , android 4.0.3

Tags: android, webview

I have used 
webview.setInitialScale(1) 
for nexus ,mdpi and ldpi devices and its working fine .Its fit to scale initially and not allowing zoom in by either double tap or pinch in buts its not working in vernet tablet(android 4.0.3).Can anyone help me .

Comment: webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

Comment: My issue is ,it should not allow to zoom

Comment: Can you try this then? webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);

Comment: I want to remove all types of zoom like double tap and pinch in .Can any one come up with solution

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

`webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);`

I hope it works.